# Courier IMAP postfix Question folders and namespace

Tags: email, postfix, imap, dovecot

So, I'm running a small email server.  On this server, I have installed and run postfix with courier-imap.  It works great, but I need to expand it's folder options for better record keeping.  Whenever I try to make a new folder, I just get subdirectories of INBOX.

I found this article, but it was no help:
http://www.courier-mta.org/FAQ.html#namespace

I understand that INBOX can't be changed.  I want to make another directory on the same level as INBOX, not as a subdirectory. From what I gather from the FAQ, courier says that it's not courier's fault!  is it possible to make another root level directory?

I tried moving to dovecot, but that had it's own host of issues.

Thanks,
P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out dovecot.  Courier is ultra reliable, but the whole "everything has to be a sub directory of INBOX" issue is just too much.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021, Courier still forces one INBOX namespace and no possiblity to create other namespaces such as Sent, Drafts, Junk, Trash, ... Everything still has to be a sub directory of INBOX.

> If OUTBOX is defined, mail can be sent via the IMAP connection by copying
> a message to the INBOX.Outbox folder.  For all practical matters,
> INBOX.Outbox looks and behaves just like any other IMAP folder.  If this
> folder doesn't exist it must be created by the IMAP mail client, just
> like any other IMAP folder.

So AFAIK Courier limits you to this:

```
002 LIST "" "%"
* LIST (\Marked \HasChildren) "." "INBOX"
```

While Dovecot allows you to have this:

```
002 LIST "" "%"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Drafts) "/" "Drafts"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "INBOX"
* LIST (\NoInferiors \Junk) "/" "Junk"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Sent) "/" "Sent"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Trash) "/" "Trash"
```